# xml in html to be read it from javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have an html file like this:

```
<html>
    <script src="/path/to/script1.js"></script>
    <xml id = "PageXML">
        <books>
            <book>
                <name>b1</name>
                <name>b2</name>
            </book>
        </books>
    </xml>
</html>
```

My question is: in Script1.js, I am able to get the xml as a text (`$('#PageXML').text()`), but I want to read the xml tag content as xml only and load it into the `xmldocument` in jquery/javascript file.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please show us what you tried until now and give us more information.

Comment: You should read it over `$.ajax(...)`. I think is better way

Comment: _"but I want to read the xml tag content as xml only"_ ? Not certain interpret this portion of Question correctly ? What is "xml only" ? Is requirement to remove `xml` from `html` document, though load `xml` into `html` document using `script1.js` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read it as HTML and parse to XML object using [**jQuery.parseXML()**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/). Then place it in any variable.

```js
xmlString = $('#PageXML')[0].outerHTML;

XMLParsed = jQuery.parseXML(xmlString);
console.log(XMLParsed);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<xml id="PageXML"><books><book><name>b1</name><name>b2</name></book></books></xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#PageXML').html()`, to get:

```
<books><book><name>b1</name><name>b2</name></book></books>
```

Comment: yes. I have used that option, but when i load that xml in the xmldocument dom parser, it's not recognizing it as valid xml.

Answer (score 0):

(i am not abler to comment yet)

After reading your comment on Filipes Answer.
Try to add a valid xml-header before passing the string to your dom Parser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<books><book><name>b1</name><name>b2</name></book></books>
```

Which XML-Parser are you using?